# Interface for Exercise by Key command in DAML node js binding?

Tags: node.js, daml

We have exercise command with contractId as one of the field. ContractId can be fetched on listening to transaction events. How can we exercise a choice if contract key is known and not contractId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Node.js bindings don't currently cover `ExerciseByKeyCommand` commands on the Ledger API:

- [Ledger API Command Specs](https://docs.daml.com/app-dev/grpc/proto-docs.html#com-daml-ledger-api-v1-command)
- [Node.js Command Specs](https://digital-asset.github.io/daml-js/latest/globals.html#command)

I've added [Issue #121](https://github.com/digital-asset/daml-js/issues/121) to the GitHub repo to track this gap.

In the meantime, you could consider using the JSON API instead for command submission, or indeed querying.

- [Exercising by Contract Key](https://docs.daml.com/json-api/index.html#exercise-by-contract-key)
- [Querying for a Contract Key](https://docs.daml.com/json-api/index.html#fetch-contract-by-key)